# Does Scala Futures/ExecutionContext have something like C#'s ConfigureAwait

Tags: scala, asynchronous, future

C#'s `Task`s have `ConfigureAwait(false)` for libraries to prevent synchronization to (for example) the UI-thread which is not always necessary:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx

In .NET I believe there can only be one `SynchonizationContext`, so it's clear on which threadpool a `Task` should execute it's continuation.
For a library, when you can't assume the user is in a webrequest(in .NET `HttpContext.Current.Items` flows), commandline (normal multithreaded), XAML/Windows Forms (single UI thread), it's almost always better to use `ConfigureAwait(false)`, so the Waiter knows it can just execute the continuation on whatever thread is being used to call the Waiter (this is only bad if you do blocking code in the library which could lead to thread starvation on the threadpool where the initial workload is started, let assume we don't do that).
The point is that from a library perspective you don't want to use a thread from the caller's threadpool to synchronize a continuation, you just want the continuation to run on whatever thread. This saves a context switch and keeps the load of the UI thread for example.

In Scala, for each operation (namely map) on Futures, you need an `ExecutionContext` (passed implicitly). This makes managing threadpools incredibly easy, which I like a lot more than the way .NET has somewhat strange `TaskFactory`'s (which nobody seems to use, they just use the default `TaskFactory`).

My question is, does Scala have the same problem as .NET in respect to context switches being sometimes unnecessary, and if so, is there a way, similar to `ConfigureAwait`, to fix this?

Concrete example I'm finding in Scala where I wonder about this:

```
def trace[T](message: => String)(block: => Future[T]): Future[T] = {
  if (!logger.isTraceEnabled) block
  else {
    val startedAt = System.currentTimeMillis()
    block.map { result =>
      val timeTaken = System.currentTimeMillis() - startedAt
      logger.trace(s"$message took ${timeTaken}ms")
      result
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using play and I generally import play's default, implicit `ExecutionContext`.
The map on `block` needs to run on an execution context.

If I wrote this piece of Scala in a library and I would add an implicit parameter `executionContext`:

```
def trace[T](message: => String)(block: => Future[T])(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext): Future[T] = {
```

instead of importing play's default `ExecutionContext` in the libary.

Comment: After writing this question I'm also wondering whether several maps in the same execution context run on the same thread in an efficient way?If so, then all of this doesn't matter that much anyway...

Comment: I've tested a series of `map` calls on a future, providing the same ExecutionContext, and it seems that `map` just uses the current thread.

Comment: Take a look at Scalaz concurrent library, it has different methods which as i understood can help you, e.g `schedule`, `timed` and `retry`